# When clicking a button all texts are showing on the same div, i want it differentely

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page, when I am doing a small task for study, it is not working. The problem is,

I have created an input box and a button, also a div for showing the texts that typed on the input box. When I typed some texts and clicked on the button, it is working.

It means the text is showing in a small div. When I typed another text and pressed the button, the div is restarting. I want a duplicate div and it should be from the below of the first. I have listed the jsfiddle below.

**JQuery Code is**

```
$(window).ready(function () {
    $(".result-box").hide();

});

$("#button4").click(function () {

    $(".result-box").show();

    $(".result-box").animate({
        top: '12%',
        left: '8%'
    });

    var vof = $("#box1").val();
    $(".result-box").text(vof);

    $("#button4").val("Next");
});
```

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saifudazzlings/0Lb1cgty/)

Comment: Js Fiddle    https://jsfiddle.net/saifudazzlings/0Lb1cgty/

Comment: Use `.append()` instead of `.text()`.

Comment: @rybo111 I think OP wants a second div below the first one, not appending to the same div.

Comment: @gcampbell Yes, but that should point the OP in the right direction. Example: `.append('<div>' + vof + '</div>');`

Comment: You should create div dynamically for every entry that will do in each time.And append to some div

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/1eLnej2h/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```js
$(window).ready(function(){
$(".result-container").hide();
});
$("#button4").click(function(){
var vof=$("#box1").val();
var newDiv ='<div class="result-box">'+vof+'</div>';
$(".result-container").append(newDiv);
$(".result-container").show();
$("#button4").val("Next");
});
```

```css
.small-box{
position:relative;
left:30%;
top:30%;
width:400px;
height:400px;
padding:30px;
border:5px solid #404040;
background:#f2f2f2;

}
.result-box{
position:relative;
left:9%;
top:10%;
border:3px solid #404040;
padding:10px;

font-family:verdana;
color:#fff;
width:80%;
background:#4d4d4d;


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="small-box">
<input type="text" id="box1" placeholder="Enter the value ?" />
<input type="button" name="button"  value="Click Me !"id="button4" /> 

<div class="result-container">
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".result-box").animate({
    top:'12%',
    left:'8%'
});

var vof=$("#box1").val();
$(".result-box").append("<div>" + vof + "</div>");

$("#button4").val("Next");
```

Comment: You should provide some explanation as to what your code does and why it works.

Answer (score 0):

See updated fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0Lb1cgty/4/

Specifically, I have changed it so that #rbx is a container, and a new div gets appended to it each time, and animated, like this:

```
$("#button4").click(function(){
  var newDiv = $("<div>", { class: "result-box"});
  newDiv.animate({
    top:'12%',
    left:'8%'
  });
  var vof=$("#box1").val();
  newDiv.text(vof);
  newDiv.appendTo($("#rbx"));
  $("#button4").val("Next");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are telling you to add new divs inside your .result-box div. While this works, you would have to update your css to reflect it.

With your current css, you could simply add a container div (.result-boxes) and append .result-box divs to that.

`<div class="result-boxes"></div>`

```
$("#button4").click(function() {

var vof = $("#box1").val();

$(".result-boxes").append("<div class='result-box'>" + vof + "</div>").animate({
  top: '12%',
  left: '8%'
});

$("#button4").val("Next");
```

});

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lb1cgty/1/).

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="small-box">
<input type="text" id="box1" placeholder="Enter the value ?">
<input type="button" name="button"  value="Click Me !"id="button4"> </input>
<div id="append"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).ready(function(){
$(".result-box").hide();

});


$("#button4").click(function(){

var vof=$("#box1").val();
$("#append").append('<div class="result-box" id="rbx">'+vof+'</div>');

$("#button4").val("Next");

$(".result-box").show();

$(".result-box").animate({

top:'12%',
left:'8%'
});
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saifudazzlings/0Lb1cgty/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dummy div which will remain hidden all the time and whatever value the user will enter second,third or nth time you can fill it in this dummy div and then append it to your main div. Something like this!!

```js
var click_made = 0;
$(window).ready(function(){
$(".result-box").hide();

});


$("#button4").click(function(){



$(".result-box").show();

$(".result-box").animate({

top:'12%',
left:'8%'


});

var vof=$("#box1").val();
if(!click_made){
$(".result-box").text(vof);
}else{
$(".dummy_div").find(".result-box").text(vof);
$(".main_container").append($(".dummy_div").html());
}

$("#button4").val("Next");
click_made = 1;




});
```

```css
.small-box{
position:relative;
left:30%;
top:30%;
width:400px;
height:400px;
padding:30px;
border:5px solid #404040;
background:#f2f2f2;

}
.result-box{
position:relative;
left:9%;
top:10%;
border:3px solid #404040;
padding:10px;

font-family:verdana;
color:#fff;
width:80%;
background:#4d4d4d;


}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="small-box">
<input type="text" id="box1" placeholder="Enter the value ?">
<input type="button" name="button"  value="Click Me !"id="button4"> </input>

<div class="main_container">
<div class="result-box" id="rbx"></div>
</div>

<div style="display:none" class="dummy_div">
<div class="result-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the meaning of this exclamation mark if(!click_made){

Comment: i've initialized click made variable with 0. so what i'm doing by (!click_made) thing is checking that if the variable is zero only then user is clicking for the first time. After the first click is made i make click_made variable 1 and thereby making the append block of code execute whenever user will click!!